# Create a fixed value "string field" based on Authrized Roles?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new with MVC5, and I want to restrict Create method to display a string field with fixed value based on Role.

in more details I want to set Region parameter with fixed value either "Jeddah, Riyadh, Alahsa" based on UserRole. if the user in Role JeddahAdminAssitant he can only create new employee that have region Jeddah and so on, please any help?

How can I achive it.
I searched  a lot and i found that I can do it by add Java scrip in Create view. 
below what I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($(Role) == 'JeddahAdminAssitant') {
        $('input[Region="Jeddah"]').prop("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
        $('input[Region="Riyadh"]').prop("disabled", false);
    }
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employees", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass role information to your view

```
@model Role

<script type="text/javascript">
    var roleName = '@Model.RoleName';

    if (roleName == 'JeddahAdminAssitant') {
    $('input[Region="Jeddah"]').prop("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
        $('input[Region="Riyadh"]').prop("disabled", false);
    }
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employees", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

or you can use role information to create html elements. for example

```
@if(Model.RoleName == "..."){
    <input ..../>
}
```

Comment: when I tried to Add @model Role but it give me error

Comment: Parser Error     Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file. Any suggestion?

Comment: @model Role is an example, you should use your own model